# How get real length of Bitset?

Tags: java, bitset

I read about size() and length() functions of BitSet class on JavaDoc and I understand the logic behind them.

But I need a function which returns the *real size*  of a BitSet (the number of bits that I inserted into it). For example following code results in 0 and 64, but I need a function which return 5.

```
BitSet test = new BitSet(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    test.set(i, false);
}
System.out.println("len = " + test.length());
System.out.println("size = " + test.size());
```

Comment: What's the point in setting bits to false? They're all already false. You can't distinguish between bits that are false because they were initialized to false, and bits that are false because you explicitly set them.

Comment: The `BitSet` does not keep track of which bits you have set to false (when they were already false). I suggest you keep count for yourself instead. The notion that it has a "real length" of 5 is a misunderstanding of what a `BitSet` is.

Comment: @Andy Turner: In my code, I have a BitSet which I insert some 1 and 0 into it. In some points, I need the current real size of my BitSet (how many bits I inserted into it) not the last position of 1.

Comment: @TailofGodzilla Why do you need it? What do you intend to use it for? What's the difference between `000101` and `000101000` to you?

Comment: @Kayaman Each bit shows the results of one step of my algorithm. I want to know the current step. I can compute it myself but I was thinking why BitSet doesn't provide it for me. If it doesn't, It is OK, I will do it myself.

Comment: Clearly it hasn't been a development goal for `BitSet`. However it's trivial to either keep a separate index variable, or just set the bit after the last to `1` every time you update the bitset. That way `length()-1` will give you the size of your results. Or just use a `List<Boolean>`, or do you have a huge amount of steps in your algorithm?

Comment: you can not `insert` bits into the BitSet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BitSet` has 3 methods that describes its state (in sense of length and set bits).

1. [`length`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#length()) - Returns the "logical size" of this BitSet: the index of the highest set bit in the BitSet plus one.
2. [`size`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#size()) - Returns the number of bits of space actually in use by this BitSet to represent bit values.
3. [`cardinality`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#cardinality()) - Returns the number of bits set to true in this BitSet.

If you need to track number of set bits `cardinality` method is the answer. Notice that it tracks *only* `true` bits.

If you need to track any call of `set` the simplest solution is to have another counter variable. So you can create a wrapper class or maybe extend `BitSet` (this can be not the best solution). Anyway, in this case you have to do it by hand.

My guess is that you thought you can treat `BitSet` as `List` or something where you have `capacity` (`size` in `BitSet` case) and `size` - the actual number of elements in a list. But for a `BitSet` only `true` bits make sense.